# A circle with radius $r$ has $k$ points within its radius. What is the min number of points a square with side $2r$ need to maintain this?

Tags: geometry, statistics

Consider that I have a circumference $c$ with radius $r$ that has $k$ points within its distance. As shown by the following graphic:

[image: circle]

For perfomance issues, 
I need to normalize this circumference into a square of side $l$ = $2r$, illustrated bellow. This mean that my basic structure is now a square of side $l$.

My question is: what is the minimum value of points $q$ to ensure that the squared circumference has at least $k$ point inside the "radius", *i.e.*, it has the same configuration of $c$ ($k$ points within the radius), 
considering that the points in the square have an uniform distribution inside the square.

For example, something as $q=factor*k$.

[image: normalized]

Comment: Is $q$ the number of points in the square? Also, are you really talking about "points" or "circles" with smaller radius?

Comment: Hi @Arash, it is points. They appear as "circles" in the image but they are points.

Comment: Isn't there always non-zero probability that all points are outside the circle?

Comment: @Arash, I'm not sure, since all points are distributed uniformally. But what number it would be if we suppose there is an uniform distribution?

Comment: You can never "ensure" that if the points are thrown at random. Do you mean that the average should be at least $k$, or that with probability (say) 90% you have at least $k$ or what?

Comment: @leonbloy, I though the uniform distribution allowed me to encounter a number $q$ that would turn this true. Nevertheless, a probability can work too. For example, 90% to be $k$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, you are going to throw $q$ points uniformly at random inside a square and want to have at least $k$ of them inside the inscribed circle.

You can never be sure of this, there will always be a probability that all points fall outside the circle. The probability that one point falls inside the circle is $\alpha=\pi/4$ (ratio of areas).

If $m$ is the number of points that fall inside the circle, then $m$ follows a binomial distribution ($q,\alpha$), with mean $q\alpha$ and variance $q \alpha (1 -\alpha)$. If you want that the average number of points is $k$, then you should pick $q = \alpha k\approx 1.27 k$

If you want instead that the probability $P(m\ge k)$ is large, you can compute the cumulative of the binomial numerically. Or you can approximate it (if $q$ is large) via the CLT. Or you can also dictate that you want that $k$ is (say) three standard deviations below the mean, so:

$$  q\alpha - k = 3 \sqrt{q \alpha (1 -\alpha)}$$
and get $q$ (as a function of $k$) from that.

Comment: Hi, leon thanks for helping.
What I want is the number of $q$ points that I need to throw to the square, considering they land uniformly distributed, that will ensure (or a percentage) that I have $k$ points inside the circumference. Which from what I read from your answer is $m$, right?